# Не удается загрузить файл в браузере puppeteer-cluster

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Я использую [puppeteer-cluster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-cluster). Мне нужно загрузить файл на сервер, через

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

Я пробовал разными способами, в том числе и с помощью `FileChooser`

Файл который мне нужен мне удается выбрать и поместить в поле выбора файла, как я понял проблема в том что он почему-то не передается на сервер.

Для проверки своей теории я создал очень просто скрипт у себя на сервере, зайдя туда с обычного браузера я без проблем загружаю файл себе на сервер.

Но если делать это через `puppeteer` - файл не загружается, скрипт ведет себя так как будто `$_POST` пустой.

Для проверки я сделал так:

```
const cluster = await Cluster.launch();

await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {
 
     await page.goto(url);
     
     await delay(999000); //просто ждем чтобы не закрылся браузер и я мог работать в нем

});
```

И вот когда запускается браузер, я вручную жму на поле выбора файла, выбираю файл, жму загрузить - и при этом сервер говорит что POST нет, но если из формы убрать `<input type="file" name="file">` и заменить его к примеру на `<input type="text" name="file">` то на сервер приходит POST.

Как решить эту проблему?

**UPD 20.01** - только что заметил такую особенность, если в puppeteer вручную открыть новую вкладку, и перейти на ту же страницу загрузки файла - то файл без проблема загружается...

**UPD** - оказывается файл не дает загрузить если используются прокси ( [puppeteer-page-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-page-proxy) )

Comment: может быть настройки безопасности или лимит на размер файла?

Comment: если открыть DevTools Networks, то файл выгружается?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor размер файла маленький, около 30кб, точно не лимит. DevTools Networks - видно что идет POST запрос, но не появляется вкладка Payload , как будто нет файла. **UPD** - только что заметил такую особенность, если в puppeteer вручную открыть новую вкладку, и перейти на ту же страницу загрузки файла - то файл без проблема загружается...